# Running process not shown in active process Instances and difference between ASYNC & SYNC tasks

Tags: asynchronous, workflow, synchronous, jbpm, kie-server

My workflow is quite simple, I have two script, first script is `ASYNC` and the second is `SYNC`. In each script I have a loop from 0 to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` as follow

```
for(int i=0;i<Integer.MAX_VALUE;i++)
   System.out.println("value is "+i);
```

When I run my process, it starts working and I can see in my log file that it is being filled. But when I want to stop it, I find nothing in my active process instances, neither in completed process or even in aborted. even if I check my data base, I have nothing related to this process in the `ProcessInstanceInfo` or even `ProcessInstanceLog`. So weird isn't it? what could be the reason?

The goal from creating this workflow is to see the difference between `ASYNC` and `SYNC` tasks, because as I know that `ASYNC` tasks when they start running, the workflow don't have to wait until this task finish, but what I have is that my task ASYNC  is still running and it didn't go to next task. So my second question is can any one give me the difference between `ASYNC` and `SYNC` with a good example to learn. I would appreciate if I'll get at least one answer on one of my two questions. thanks

Answer (score 0):

What do you stop? Do you abort the process instance ?

In the scripts you can populate the process variables with `kcontext.setVariable("variable_name","variable_value")`. This will reflect in DB if you have defined the process variable persistent in the process model.

The tasks, the sync one will return the flow control to the process when is completed. In contrast to the async one, process flow will continue immediately after it sends the async tasks to execute.

Comment: the problem is that the process Instance id is not persisted into the table if the first task is a script task, I think it's a bug in Jbpm, you didn't understand the question once again

Comment: That is true. Until you are in the script, it will not. That is because before that there was only a start signal. I think if the process instance is on signal and escript, the process instance is still in memory, and on the first node, it will save the state in the table. If the process is active, you will have a record in processinstanceinfo table. But I have processes waitng on the first signal after the start and those are saved in table record alredy.